# Subsubsection numbering in IEEEtran Computer Society Journals template bleeds into text

Tags: sectioning, ieeetran, journal

I'm using a modified `IEEEtran` class with the template for Computer Society Journals (found [here](https://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html)).

When I produce a PDF of the basic demo (using Texmaker), I noticed that the numbering for subsubsections bleeds into the text:

[image]

I can't find anything related to this issue. I'm still learning LaTeX and so I don't know enough to tell whether this is an issue with the template/class or Texmaker.

**EDIT**

Here's a sample code that's being used to generate a subsection:

```
\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls\\ for Computer Society Journals}

\author{Michael~Shell,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
        John~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Fellow,~OSA,}
        and~Jane~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Life~Fellow,~IEEE}% <-this % stops a space
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{\IEEEcompsocthanksitem M. Shell is with the Department
of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta,
GA, 30332.\protect\\
% note need leading \protect in front of \\ to get a newline within \thanks as
% \\ is fragile and will error, could use \hfil\break instead.
E-mail: see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html
\IEEEcompsocthanksitem J. Doe and J. Doe are with Anonymous University.}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Manuscript received April 19, 2005; revised January 11, 2007.}}

% The paper headers
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~6, No.~1, January~2007}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Computer Society Journals}

\IEEEcompsoctitleabstractindextext{%
\begin{abstract}
%\boldmath
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

% Note that keywords are not normally used for peerreview papers.
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Computer Society, IEEEtran, journal, \LaTeX, paper, template.
\end{IEEEkeywords}}


% make the title area
\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} demo file is intended to serve as a ``starter file''
for IEEE Computer Society journal papers produced under \LaTeX\ using
IEEEtran.cls version 1.7 and later.
% You must have at least 2 lines in the paragraph with the drop letter
% (should never be an issue)
I wish you the best of success.

\hfill mds

\hfill January 11, 2007

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Subsection text here.


\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Subsubsection text here.

% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

I noticed that this happens for both the conference and journal templates.

Comment: Perhaps provide a code sample.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I've added some code. There's some stuff related to subsubsection inside the class file, and so I will post that as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IEEEtran.cls` you've downloaded is a modified version of the one you can find on CTAN.

And it is clearly buggy...

It contains the lines

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\hb@xt@ 1.4em{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hss\relax}}
\def\@seccntformatinl#1{\hb@xt@ 1.1em{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hss\relax}}
\def\@seccntformatch#1{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hskip 1em\relax}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
% compsoc journals need extra spacing
\ifCLASSOPTIONconference\else
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hskip 1em\relax}
\fi\fi
```

which are wrong. They should be

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\hb@xt@ 1.4em{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hss\relax}}
\def\@seccntformatinl#1{\hb@xt@ 1.1em{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hss\relax}}
\def\@seccntformatch#1{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hskip 1em\relax}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
% compsoc journals need extra spacing
\ifCLASSOPTIONconference\else
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hskip 1em\relax}
\def\@seccntformatinl#1{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hskip 1em\relax}
\fi\fi
```

You should report this bug.

As a workaround, you can add the following lines just before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformatinl#1{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hskip 1em\relax}
\makeatother
```

MWE (excerpt from `bare_jrnl_compsoc.tex` template)

```
\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformatinl#1{\csname the#1dis\endcsname\hskip 1em\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls\\ for Computer Society Journals}

\author{Michael~Shell,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
        John~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Fellow,~OSA,}
        and~Jane~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Life~Fellow,~IEEE}% <-this % stops a space
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{\IEEEcompsocthanksitem M. Shell is with the Department
of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta,
GA, 30332.\protect\\
% note need leading \protect in front of \\ to get a newline within \thanks as
% \\ is fragile and will error, could use \hfil\break instead.
E-mail: see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html
\IEEEcompsocthanksitem J. Doe and J. Doe are with Anonymous University.}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Manuscript received April 19, 2005; revised January 11, 2007.}}

% The paper headers
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~6, No.~1, January~2007}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Computer Society Journals}

\IEEEcompsoctitleabstractindextext{%
\begin{abstract}
%\boldmath
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

% Note that keywords are not normally used for peerreview papers.
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Computer Society, IEEEtran, journal, \LaTeX, paper, template.
\end{IEEEkeywords}}


% make the title area
\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} demo file is intended to serve as a ``starter file''
for IEEE Computer Society journal papers produced under \LaTeX\ using
IEEEtran.cls version 1.7 and later.
% You must have at least 2 lines in the paragraph with the drop letter
% (should never be an issue)
I wish you the best of success.

\hfill mds

\hfill January 11, 2007

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Subsection text here.


\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Subsubsection text here.

% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I don't know how much the modified `IEEEtran.cls` you've downloaded differs from the official one on CTAN, but you can probably delete the one you've downloaded and use the official one in your TeX distro, which doesn't have that problem at all.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it was available on CTAN. I will report the issue to IEEE as well.